# Where ReplicaSet Ids are maintained in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a cluster of 3 nodes, 1 Primary and 2 secondary.
I am trying to point **db path** in config, of primary node to some other folder location.
But, after doing so,when i started up the cluster again. A new primary node is elected and the old primary node was not able to connect back in cluster, with status as **OTHER**
On inspecting logs, I found there is something wrong with the replica set Ids.
It says *`replica set IDs do not match, ours: 59a977041512950ca962ae3d; remote node's: 59b9075eda8af59061bae9f8`*
So, just wanted to know where this piece of information is stored and how should i update it.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**